# Overfull and underfull boxes when using twoside documents and fancy headers

Tags: spacing

I am facing some problems with underfull vbox and overfull hbox while \output is active.

When I am using the document class like: `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{report}`, I got no messages about any problem. But when I change it to `\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}` these messages start to appear. I tried to remove the "openright" parameter, but still returns the message.

I can get rid some of these messages removing the package `\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}`, and setting the property `heightrounded = true` in the geometry package.

Mostly of the pages where this occurs have images and in some cases, latex appears to include some space between lines for apparently no reason, like in the figure bellow:

[image: Space between lines]

The text shown above is consecutive in the latex file, there is no image between the lines or anything like this.

In my research, I have found nothing that could help me. I anyone have any idea on how to proceed to adjust properly these spaces, I would be grateful.

P.S.: I tried to create a sample document, but when I ran the code that generates the text shown in figure above alone, the spaces didn't appear. It only appears in the entire document.

UPDATE: I was able to generate a code that reproduces one of this issue. It seems that the matrix is the problem here...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}

% =============================================================================
% Pacotes utilizados
\usepackage[english, brazil]{babel} % Português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Adiciona parágrafo na primeira linha da seção
\usepackage{microtype} % Melhoras nos espaços entre palavras e letras
\usepackage{amsmath} % Equações
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array} % Traz algumas funcionalidades úteis
\usepackage{verbatim} % Traz algumas funcionalidades úteis
\usepackage{graphicx} % Figuras
\usepackage{epstopdf} % Converte as imagens em EPS para PDF
\usepackage{caption} % Para importar o subcaption
\usepackage{subcaption} % Para usar subfiguras
\usepackage{algorithm} % Ambiente para escrever algoritmos
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} % Ajuste da margem
\usepackage{setspace} % Ajuste de espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap} % Capítulos bonitos: Lenny, Sonny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
\usepackage{cite} % Melhorias nas citações
%\usepackage{times} % Usa fonte Times no texto
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % Usa fonte times no texto e nas equações

% =============================================================================
% Definições de Estilo

% Margens
% Definidas segundo as normas da ABNT apresentadas no Guia de Normalização da UFABC: Margens superior e esquerda igual a 3 cm e inferior e direita igual a 2 cm.
\geometry{
    top = 30mm,
    left = 30mm,
    bottom = 20mm,
    right = 20mm,
    heightrounded = true
}

\linespread{1.3}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\pagestyle{headings} % Mostra o título do capítulo atual no topo da página

\begin{document}

\chapter{Estimador de Canal Least Squares}
\label{chap:estimador_canal_ls}

O estimador mais simples que pode ser encontrado em qualquer literatura de estimação é, sem dúvida, o estimador chamado de mínimos quadrados (LS, do inglês \textit{Least Squares}). No estimador LS, busca-se minimizar o quadrado da diferença entre um certo dado e a sua versão original, ou sem ruído.

O sinal recebido pelo nó 1, cujas equações são reescritas abaixo por conveniência, podem ser representadas na forma de um modelo linear.
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Sinal_recebido_no_1_b_2}
y_{1}(n) = x_{1}(n) \ast a(n) + x_{2}(n) \ast b(n) + w(n),
\end{equation}
onde $ a(n) = h_{1R}(n) \ast h_{R2}(n) $, $ b(n) = h_{2R}(n) \ast h_{R2}(n) $, e $ w(n) = w_{R}(n) \ast h_{R1}(n) + w_{1}(n) $.

Reescrevendo-as de forma matricial, podemos definir uma matriz $ \mathbf{X} = \left[ \mathbf{X}_{1} \\\ \mathbf{X}_{2} \right] $, onde

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X}_{i} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{i}(0)   &     0      &     0      & \cdots & 0 \\
x_{i}(1)   & x_{i}(0)   &     0      & \cdots & 0 \\
x_{i}(2)   & x_{i}(1)   & x_{i}(0)   & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots    &  \vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{i}(N-1) & x_{i}(N-2) & x_{i}(N-3) & \cdots & \\
0      & x_{i}(N-1) & x_{i}(N-2) & \cdots & \\
0      &     0      & x_{i}(N-1) & \cdots & \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & \\
\vdots    &  \vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-3) \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-2) \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-1) \\
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
que é uma matriz de convolução de dimensões $ N + 2*N_{CH} -1 \times 2*Nch $. 

Define-se também o vetor que contem os coeficientes de ambos os canais:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{a} \\
\mathbf{b}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
onde $ \mathbf{a} = \left[ a(0) \\\ a(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ a(2N_{CH} - 1) \right]^{T} $ e $ \mathbf{b} = \left[ b(0) \\\ b(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ b(2N_{CH} - 1) \right]^{T} $, contendo, respectivamente, os coeficientes dos canais $ a $ e $ b $, um vetor $ \mathbf{w} = \left[ w_(0) \\\ w_(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ w(N-1) \right]^{T} $, e um vetor $ \mathbf{y} = \left[ y_{1}(0) \\\ y_{1}(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ y_{1}(N-1) \right]^{T} $.

Pode-se então, reescrever a equação \ref{eq:Sinal_recebido_no_1_b_2} em sua forma matricial:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sinal_recebido_no_1_matricial}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{h} + \mathbf{w}.
\end{equation}

Para realizar a estimação de canal, portanto, é necessário que o estimador conheça a matriz $ \mathbf{X} $. Portanto, são utilizadas sequências de treinamento, de forma que possa-se montar uma matriz $ \mathbf{M} $, composta, de forma idêntica à $ \mathbf{X} $, pelas matrizes de convolução $ \mathbf{M}_{1} $ e $ \mathbf{M}_{2} $ compostas pelas sequências de treinamento enviadas pelo nó 1 e 2, respectivamente. Pode-se, então, reescrever a equação  da seguinte forma:

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sinal_treinamento_recebido_no_1_matricial}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} + \mathbf{w}.
\end{equation}

A partir desse modelo linear, pode-se escrever o problema dos mínimos quadrados para a estimação de $ \mathbf{h} $  como:

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{h}} = \argmin_{h} |\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h}|^{2}.
\end{equation}

A solução para esse problema, pode ser obtido através de:

\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{h}} = \mathbf{M}^{\dagger}\mathbf{y},
\end{equation}
onde $ \mathbf{M}^{\dagger} $ denota a matriz pseudoinversa de $ \mathbf{M} $ e é dada por:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}^{\dagger} = (\mathbf{M}^{T} \mathbf{M})^{-1} \mathbf{M}^{T}.
\end{equation}

% A derivação da expressão acima pode ser encontrada no livro do Kay de teoria da estimação, na página 84 e 85, capítulo 4 (Linear Models).



\end{document}
```

Comment: The extra space is because you are using the (default) flushbottom setting and with the large non-breakable displays the only way tex can maintain a consistent position for the last line on the page is to stretch the content. You may prefer `\raggedbottom` (as used in article class by default) in which any extra space is placed at the bottom of the page.

Comment: This command is also very useful. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your lines are very spaced out anyway, you could consider cramping the baseline spacing for this array

[image]

note I removed all the blank lines before math displays

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}

% =============================================================================
% Pacotes utilizados
\usepackage[english, brazil]{babel} % Português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Adiciona parágrafo na primeira linha da seção
\usepackage{microtype} % Melhoras nos espaços entre palavras e letras
\usepackage{amsmath} % Equações
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array} % Traz algumas funcionalidades úteis
\usepackage{verbatim} % Traz algumas funcionalidades úteis
\usepackage{graphicx} % Figuras
\usepackage{epstopdf} % Converte as imagens em EPS para PDF
\usepackage{caption} % Para importar o subcaption
\usepackage{subcaption} % Para usar subfiguras
\usepackage{algorithm} % Ambiente para escrever algoritmos
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} % Ajuste da margem
\usepackage{setspace} % Ajuste de espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap} % Capítulos bonitos: Lenny, Sonny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
\usepackage{cite} % Melhorias nas citações
%\usepackage{times} % Usa fonte Times no texto
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % Usa fonte times no texto e nas equações

% =============================================================================
% Definições de Estilo

% Margens
% Definidas segundo as normas da ABNT apresentadas no Guia de Normalização da UFABC: Margens superior e esquerda igual a 3 cm e inferior e direita igual a 2 cm.

\linespread{1.3}

\geometry{
    top = 30mm,
    left = 30mm,
    bottom = 20mm,
    right = 20mm,
    heightrounded = true
}



\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\pagestyle{headings} % Mostra o título do capítulo atual no topo da página

\begin{document}


\chapter{Estimador de Canal Least Squares}
\label{chap:estimador_canal_ls}

O estimador mais simples que pode ser encontrado em qualquer literatura de estimação é, sem dúvida, o estimador chamado de mínimos quadrados (LS, do inglês \textit{Least Squares}). No estimador LS, busca-se minimizar o quadrado da diferença entre um certo dado e a sua versão original, ou sem ruído.

O sinal recebido pelo nó 1, cujas equações são reescritas abaixo por conveniência, podem ser representadas na forma de um modelo linear.
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Sinal_recebido_no_1_b_2}
y_{1}(n) = x_{1}(n) \ast a(n) + x_{2}(n) \ast b(n) + w(n),
\end{equation}
onde $ a(n) = h_{1R}(n) \ast h_{R2}(n) $, $ b(n) = h_{2R}(n) \ast h_{R2}(n) $, e $ w(n) = w_{R}(n) \ast h_{R1}(n) + w_{1}(n) $.

Reescrevendo-as de forma matricial, podemos definir uma matriz $ \mathbf{X} = \left[ \mathbf{X}_{1} \\\ \mathbf{X}_{2} \right] $, onde
\begin{equation}\renewcommand\arraystretch{.8}
\mathbf{X}_{i} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{i}(0)   &     0      &     0      & \cdots & 0 \\
x_{i}(1)   & x_{i}(0)   &     0      & \cdots & 0 \\
x_{i}(2)   & x_{i}(1)   & x_{i}(0)   & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots    &  \vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{i}(N-1) & x_{i}(N-2) & x_{i}(N-3) & \cdots & \\
0      & x_{i}(N-1) & x_{i}(N-2) & \cdots & \\
0      &     0      & x_{i}(N-1) & \cdots & \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & \\
\vdots    &  \vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-3) \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-2) \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-1) \\
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
que é uma matriz de convolução de dimensões $ N + 2*N_{CH} -1 \times 2*Nch $. 

Define-se também o vetor que contem os coeficientes de ambos os canais:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{a} \\
\mathbf{b}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
onde $ \mathbf{a} = \left[ a(0) \\\ a(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ a(2N_{CH} - 1) \right]^{T} $ e $ \mathbf{b} = \left[ b(0) \\\ b(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ b(2N_{CH} - 1) \right]^{T} $, contendo, respectivamente, os coeficientes dos canais $ a $ e $ b $, um vetor $ \mathbf{w} = \left[ w_(0) \\\ w_(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ w(N-1) \right]^{T} $, e um vetor $ \mathbf{y} = \left[ y_{1}(0) \\\ y_{1}(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ y_{1}(N-1) \right]^{T} $.

Pode-se então, reescrever a equação \ref{eq:Sinal_recebido_no_1_b_2} em sua forma matricial:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sinal_recebido_no_1_matricial}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{h} + \mathbf{w}.
\end{equation}

Para realizar a estimação de canal, portanto, é necessário que o estimador conheça a matriz $ \mathbf{X} $. Portanto, são utilizadas sequências de treinamento, de forma que possa-se montar uma matriz $ \mathbf{M} $, composta, de forma idêntica à $ \mathbf{X} $, pelas matrizes de convolução $ \mathbf{M}_{1} $ e $ \mathbf{M}_{2} $ compostas pelas sequências de treinamento enviadas pelo nó 1 e 2, respectivamente. Pode-se, então, reescrever a equação  da seguinte forma:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sinal_treinamento_recebido_no_1_matricial}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} + \mathbf{w}.
\end{equation}

A partir desse modelo linear, pode-se escrever o problema dos mínimos quadrados para a estimação de $ \mathbf{h} $  como:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{h}} = \argmin_{h} |\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h}|^{2}.
\end{equation}

A solução para esse problema, pode ser obtido através de:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{h}} = \mathbf{M}^{\dagger}\mathbf{y},
\end{equation}
onde $ \mathbf{M}^{\dagger} $ denota a matriz pseudoinversa de $ \mathbf{M} $ e é dada por:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}^{\dagger} = (\mathbf{M}^{T} \mathbf{M})^{-1} \mathbf{M}^{T}.
\end{equation}

% A derivação da expressão acima pode ser encontrada no livro do Kay de teoria da estimação, na página 84 e 85, capítulo 4 (Linear Models).



\end{document}
```

Or since the last 3 rows don't carry any real information in this case, just use 2 rows at the end:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright]{report}

% =============================================================================
% Pacotes utilizados
\usepackage[english, brazil]{babel} % Português do Brasil
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{indentfirst} % Adiciona parágrafo na primeira linha da seção
\usepackage{microtype} % Melhoras nos espaços entre palavras e letras
\usepackage{amsmath} % Equações
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array} % Traz algumas funcionalidades úteis
\usepackage{verbatim} % Traz algumas funcionalidades úteis
\usepackage{graphicx} % Figuras
\usepackage{epstopdf} % Converte as imagens em EPS para PDF
\usepackage{caption} % Para importar o subcaption
\usepackage{subcaption} % Para usar subfiguras
\usepackage{algorithm} % Ambiente para escrever algoritmos
\usepackage{geometry}
%\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry} % Ajuste da margem
\usepackage{setspace} % Ajuste de espaçamento entre linhas
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap} % Capítulos bonitos: Lenny, Sonny, Glenn, Conny, Rejne, Bjarne, Bjornstrup
\usepackage{cite} % Melhorias nas citações
%\usepackage{times} % Usa fonte Times no texto
%\usepackage{mathptmx} % Usa fonte times no texto e nas equações

% =============================================================================
% Definições de Estilo

% Margens
% Definidas segundo as normas da ABNT apresentadas no Guia de Normalização da UFABC: Margens superior e esquerda igual a 3 cm e inferior e direita igual a 2 cm.

\linespread{1.3}

\geometry{
    top = 30mm,
    left = 30mm,
    bottom = 20mm,
    right = 20mm,
    heightrounded = true
}



\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

\pagestyle{headings} % Mostra o título do capítulo atual no topo da página

\begin{document}


\chapter{Estimador de Canal Least Squares}
\label{chap:estimador_canal_ls}

O estimador mais simples que pode ser encontrado em qualquer literatura de estimação é, sem dúvida, o estimador chamado de mínimos quadrados (LS, do inglês \textit{Least Squares}). No estimador LS, busca-se minimizar o quadrado da diferença entre um certo dado e a sua versão original, ou sem ruído.

O sinal recebido pelo nó 1, cujas equações são reescritas abaixo por conveniência, podem ser representadas na forma de um modelo linear.
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:Sinal_recebido_no_1_b_2}
y_{1}(n) = x_{1}(n) \ast a(n) + x_{2}(n) \ast b(n) + w(n),
\end{equation}
onde $ a(n) = h_{1R}(n) \ast h_{R2}(n) $, $ b(n) = h_{2R}(n) \ast h_{R2}(n) $, e $ w(n) = w_{R}(n) \ast h_{R1}(n) + w_{1}(n) $.

Reescrevendo-as de forma matricial, podemos definir uma matriz $ \mathbf{X} = \left[ \mathbf{X}_{1} \\\ \mathbf{X}_{2} \right] $, onde
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X}_{i} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{i}(0)   &     0      &     0      & \cdots & 0 \\
x_{i}(1)   & x_{i}(0)   &     0      & \cdots & 0 \\
x_{i}(2)   & x_{i}(1)   & x_{i}(0)   & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots    &  \vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{i}(N-1) & x_{i}(N-2) & x_{i}(N-3) & \cdots & \\
0      & x_{i}(N-1) & x_{i}(N-2) & \cdots & \\
0      &     0      & x_{i}(N-1) & \cdots & \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & \\
\vdots    &  \vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
%0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-3) \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-2) \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-1) \\
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
que é uma matriz de convolução de dimensões $ N + 2*N_{CH} -1 \times 2*Nch $. 

Define-se também o vetor que contem os coeficientes de ambos os canais:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{h} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{a} \\
\mathbf{b}
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
onde $ \mathbf{a} = \left[ a(0) \\\ a(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ a(2N_{CH} - 1) \right]^{T} $ e $ \mathbf{b} = \left[ b(0) \\\ b(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ b(2N_{CH} - 1) \right]^{T} $, contendo, respectivamente, os coeficientes dos canais $ a $ e $ b $, um vetor $ \mathbf{w} = \left[ w_(0) \\\ w_(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ w(N-1) \right]^{T} $, e um vetor $ \mathbf{y} = \left[ y_{1}(0) \\\ y_{1}(1) \\\ \cdots \\\ y_{1}(N-1) \right]^{T} $.

Pode-se então, reescrever a equação \ref{eq:Sinal_recebido_no_1_b_2} em sua forma matricial:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sinal_recebido_no_1_matricial}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{h} + \mathbf{w}.
\end{equation}

Para realizar a estimação de canal, portanto, é necessário que o estimador conheça a matriz $ \mathbf{X} $. Portanto, são utilizadas sequências de treinamento, de forma que possa-se montar uma matriz $ \mathbf{M} $, composta, de forma idêntica à $ \mathbf{X} $, pelas matrizes de convolução $ \mathbf{M}_{1} $ e $ \mathbf{M}_{2} $ compostas pelas sequências de treinamento enviadas pelo nó 1 e 2, respectivamente. Pode-se, então, reescrever a equação  da seguinte forma:
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:sinal_treinamento_recebido_no_1_matricial}
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h} + \mathbf{w}.
\end{equation}

A partir desse modelo linear, pode-se escrever o problema dos mínimos quadrados para a estimação de $ \mathbf{h} $  como:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{h}} = \argmin_{h} |\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{M} \mathbf{h}|^{2}.
\end{equation}

A solução para esse problema, pode ser obtido através de:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\mathbf{h}} = \mathbf{M}^{\dagger}\mathbf{y},
\end{equation}
onde $ \mathbf{M}^{\dagger} $ denota a matriz pseudoinversa de $ \mathbf{M} $ e é dada por:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{M}^{\dagger} = (\mathbf{M}^{T} \mathbf{M})^{-1} \mathbf{M}^{T}.
\end{equation}

% A derivação da expressão acima pode ser encontrada no livro do Kay de teoria da estimação, na página 84 e 85, capítulo 4 (Linear Models).



\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi! Both suggestions work great for me! I think i will adopt the last one: removing one row, but it is really helpful to know the arraystretch. Thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to tex.sx.

you really shouldn't leave a blank line above an `equation` or other
display -- it will always add space, and also permit a page break where
it's really not considered good style.

but the real problem here, as you  point out, is that the matrix simply
won't fit in the remaining space on the page.

in this case, it may be just barely acceptable to reduce the size of
that display.  making just this modification will reduce the size to
something that will fit;

```
Reescrevendo-as de forma matricial, podemos definir uma matriz $ \mathbf{X} = \left[ \mathbf{X}_{1} \\\ \mathbf{X}_{2} \right] $, onde
\begingroup
\small    
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{X}_{i} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
x_{i}(0)   &     0      &     0      & \cdots & 0 \\
x_{i}(1)   & x_{i}(0)   &     0      & \cdots & 0 \\
x_{i}(2)   & x_{i}(1)   & x_{i}(0)   & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots    &  \vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{i}(N-1) & x_{i}(N-2) & x_{i}(N-3) & \cdots & \\
0      & x_{i}(N-1) & x_{i}(N-2) & \cdots & \\
0      &     0      & x_{i}(N-1) & \cdots & \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & \\
\vdots    &  \vdots    &  \vdots    & \ddots & \vdots \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-3) \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-2) \\
0      &     0      &     0      & \cdots & x_{i}(N-1) \\
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}
\endgroup
que é uma matriz de convolução de dimensões $ N + 2*N_{CH} -1 \times 2*Nch $.
```

(since you're using amsmath, the size of the equation number will not be
reduced.)

this approach isn't generally recommended, and if the preceding paragraph
has more than one line, additional complications arise that must be dealt with (the line spacing is reduced).
so it's a tactic for emergency use only.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the welcome. It really works for me, but as you said it isn't a good practice, I accepted David answer as correct, once it also works for me. Anyway, thanks a lot for your time and effort.

Comment: And thanks for the tip about lines before an equation. I am going to correct this.